# Microsoft SQL server View of multiple conditional statements with UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause, sql-view

Is there any way to achieve the following behavior in Microsoft SQL server ?

A view with several SQL statements which can be invoked according to parameters passed to the view.

The view should look like this:

```
if param.contains "a"

  select name from table1

if param.contains "b"

  select name from table2

if param.contains "c"

  select name from table3
```

Between all the `IF`s I want to have a `UNION`, such that if more than one condition is true, the result is a `UNION` of all these conditions results.

The view will be invoked this way for example (psuedo):

```
SELECT * FROM myView where param IN {"a", "b"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
create view myview as
select 'a' cat, name from table1
union all select 'b', name from table2
union all select 'c', name from table3
```

Then you can query the view like so:

```
select * from myview where cat in ('a', 'b');
```

Comment: Where exactly does the condition take place? I see no IFs of Case, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Daher928: the condition is not a parameter to the view (views don't take parameters). Instead, the view has a fixed value that indicates from which table each record comes from, that you can use as a filter in your query (as shown).